# Numpy array normalization by group ids:

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis

Suppose **data** and **labels** be **numpy arrays** as below:

```
import numpy as np
data=np.array([[0,4,5,6,8],[0,6,8,9],[1,9,5],[1,45,7],[1,8,3]]) #Note: length of each row is different 
labels=np.array([4,6,10,4,6])
```

The **first element in each row** in **data** shows **an id of a group**. I want **to normalize** (see below example) **the labels** based on the **group ids**:

For example the first two rows in data have id=0; thus, their label must be:

```
normalized_labels[0]=labels[0]/(4+6)=0.4 
normalized_labels[1]=labels[1]/(4+6)=0.6
```

The expected output should be:

```
normalized_labels=[0.4,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.3]
```

I have a naive solution as:

```
ids=[data[i][0] for i in range(data.shape[0])]
out=[]
for i in set(ids):
    ind=np.where(ids==i)
    out.extend(list(labels[ind]/np.sum(labels[ind])))
out=np.array(out)
print(out)
```

Is there any numpy functions to perform such a task. Any suggestion is appreciated!!

Comment: The size of `data` items is unbalanced. Is it alright?

Comment: Yes, it is unbalanced. Each row in data  has different length.

Comment: Well, in that case no vectorized solution is possible. I would use `indices = [n[0] for n in data]` in order to extract indices needed. After you have done it, `data` variable could be omitted and further solution could be vectorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this kind of subtle way to transform `labels` into sums of groups with respect to `indices = [n[0] for n in data]`. In later solution, no use of `data` is needed:

```
indices = [n[0] for n in data]
u, inv = np.unique(indices, return_inverse=True)
bincnt = np.bincount(inv, weights=labels)
sums = bincnt[inv]
```

Now sums are: `array([10., 10., 20., 20., 20.])`. The further is simple like so:

```
normalized_labels = labels / sums
```

**Remarks.** `np.bincount` calculates weighted sums of items labeled as 0, 1, 2... This is why reindexation `indices -> inv` is needed. For example, `indices = [8, 6, 4, 3, 4, 6, 8, 8]` should be mapped into `inv = [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3]`.